# I am confused about some specific types of domains and ranges that are provided in questions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

There are some specific type of questions based on functions which map from some domain to range which is confusing to me... For example, can someone explain what sort of mapping is this:

> $g: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2, \ \ g(x,y) = (x+y, 3x-y)$

How to prove that it is bijective?

Comment: To show it's bijective you need to show that the map is injective (this is sufficient since g is an endomorphism on a finite dimensional vector space). To do this, you want to show that $null(g)=0$.

Comment: What does null(g) = 0 mean? Is there any formal mathematical way of proofing whether the function is both injective and surjective? And what does the mapping from R^2 to R^2 mean?

Comment: $null(g)=0$ means that the dimension of the kernel of $g$ is 0 (so the only solution to $g(x,y)=0$ is if x=y=0). If you can show that the function has this property, then it is injective. Automatically (if it is injective) the function is surjective (since g is an endomorphism on a finite dimensional vector space). The mapping from $\Bbb R^2$ to itself is saying that you are taking a vector in $\Bbb R^2$ (which can be thought of as a pair (x,y)), and applying the function $g$, and the output is another vector in $\Bbb R^2$ (of the form (x+y,3x-y)$).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: your mapping is linear. Can you represent it as matrix multiplication?

Comment: I am sorry but I am not familiar with matrices